# How to get HTML content of A webpage Using Javascript by an URL only?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I tried to get html element of a webpage using jquery and an URL.

Hi, I am new in web development. I am learnig day by day. Today I tried to get the content of a webpage using jquery and an URL. But not able to get content. I get help from AI, but it's not working.

Here's my URL https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/2023/05/perfect-fried-rice-plate-is-really.html, from where I want to get the value of `<span class="eta" id="etawrap"></span>` spans. I tried this way, but not getting.

My Approach:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-div"></div>

<script>
  const url = "https://tailwindbt.blogspot.com/2023/05/perfect-fried-rice-plate-is-really.html";
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    const parsedHtml = $.parseHTML(data);
    const span = $(parsedHtml).find("#etawrap");
    const textContent = span.text();
    $(".my-div").html(textContent);
  });
</script>
```

But its not working. What I can do ?

Comment: You're selecting the span in your own document and not in the fetched resource. Also this is not jQuery at all.

Comment: @DallogFheir How can I get it ? Please assist me brother.

Comment: Set `xhr.responseType = "document"`, then query `html.querySelector("#etawrap")`.

Comment: If you check the console for errors you'll see that the problem is because the URL you're calling does not include CORS headers in the response. Therefore you will not be able to make an AJAX request to it from client-side JS. See the duplicate for more information. The workaround for this is to make the request from the server side instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated code. Please see now.

Comment: Updating your client-side code is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so how can I get it ?

Comment: Did you even read my first comment?